# Python code help! Code academy isnt being helpful

Tags: python, python-2.7

[Code and instructions found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3ZFM.png)

```
 shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}

# Write your code below!
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        total += item
    return total
```

Above is my code, i understand it needs to find the values but even if i try food.values() it gives an error. How can i make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Post your code as text, not a link to an image

Comment: Title needs more detail (You need to describe your problem in title), also, as EdChum said, it is better if you write your code and not link it.

Comment: And which values are you trying to find?

Comment: literally everythng is listed in the picture. its from code academy.

Comment: wrong `return` position, missing `key value` ! etc. so not work

Comment: Please title your questions more helpfully in the future. This title doesn't let anyone understand what the subject really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your code as a CODE/text, not pictures!
anyway, just a very raw implementation without any checks/validations would be something like:

```
def computer_bill(food):
    total = 0.0
    for i in food:
        if i in prices:
            total += float(prices[i])
    return total


stock = {
"banana": 6,
"apple": 0,
"orange": 32,
"pear": 15
}

prices = {
"banana": 4,
"apple": 2,
"orange": 1.5,
"pear": 3
}

print "-------"
lfood = ["banana","orange"]
print "total is:", computer_bill(lfood)
```

### **output:**

*total is: 5.5*